# ftp debian repository is failling when updating

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt

I have an ubuntu 16.04 server running in Vagrant. When I run `apt-get update` I get the following error:

```
Err:1 http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
  Could not connect to ftp.es.debian.org:80 (82.194.78.250). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:4 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ InRelease
Hit:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:10 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Release
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:12 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Packages
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Ign:12 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Packages
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Ign:12 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Packages
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Hit:12 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Packages
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Ign:13 http://3.209.89.143/repo amd64/ Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not connect to ftp.es.debian.org:80 (82.194.78.250). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

These are the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb [trusted=yes] http://3.209.89.143/repo/ amd64/
deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

I have tried a ton of solutions but I cannot solve it, any idea what's going on? Do you need more data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `ftp.es.debian.org` is currently down. You can replace `http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian/` in your `sources.list` by `http://deb.debian.org/debian/` which should automatically select a working mirror. Make sure to run `apt-get update` afterwards.

Comment: Yes, one should mention that this isn't a very good idea in general.

Comment: I presume that Mint & Debian tags mean that the OP is using LMDE - the Debian edition of Mint. No Ubuntu repo's are used!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove debian repositories from your `sources.list`:

```
sudo sed -i '/debian/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```